# How to delete last items from a list that's in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have this dictionary:

```
b_dict = {
    "greetings": ["hello", "hey", "hi"],
    "vehicle": ["car,plane,boat"],
    "home": ["house", "apartment", "mansion"],
    "electronics": ["tv", "computer", "laptop"]}
```

I would like to remove the two last item from each of the lists in the dictionary:
For example:

```
b_dict = {
    "greetings": ["hello"],
    "vehicle": ["car"],
    "home": ["house"],
    "electronics": ["tv"]}
```

I tried something like this:

```
def extract_top_words(): 
    for value in b_dict:
        if len(b_dict[value]) > 2:
            del (b_dict[value])[2:]     
    return b_dict
```

But that didn't work. Feel like I am doing an indexing mistake or I am not using the del operator properly.

Comment: "But that didn't work". How did it not work?

Comment: `"car,plane,boat"` is one string. Is that a typo? It's more obvious now that I've improved the code style. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really close. Try this instead:

```
def extract_top_words():
    for value in b_dict:
        if len(b_dict[value]) > 2:
            del (b_dict[value])[-2:]
    return b_dict
```

output:

```
{'greetings': ['hello'],
 'vehicle': ['car,plane,boat'],
 'home': ['house'],
 'electronics': ['tv']}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all,

```
del (b_dict[value])[2:]
```

indexes element 2 through the end, *not* the last two elements (unless the list has exactly four elements).  Also, `del` is a very heavy-handed way to delete items.  Simply slice out the ones you don't want:

```
b_dict[value] = b_dict[value][:-2]
```

You could also `pop` the last two elements.  Better yet, it appears that what you want is specifically to keep only the first element:

```
b_dict[value] = b_dict[value][0]
```

... in which case, you finish with a simple string, rather than a list.

Answer (score 0):

Very close.

```
def extract_top_words(): 
    for key in b_dict:
        b_dict[key] = b_dict[key][:-2]
    return b_dict
```

or, a cute way:

```
def extract_top_words(): 
    for value in b_dict.values():
        value.pop()
        value.pop()
    return b_dict
```

Comment: Very nice, I understand, but I have question: What if the lists were of different sizes, I mean like one list could have 3 elements, and another could have had 15 elements, and so on. How would I still only keep the first two?

Comment: "Keep the first two" is different from "delete the last two".  The way to do that in place is `value[2:] = []`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple dict comprehension can do it for you:

```
b_dict = {key: val[:-2] for key, val in b_dict.items()}
```